# Any solution for accelerating the reading of data from disk and converting them into numpy array for further processing?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing, gdal

Is there any solution for accelerating the reading of raster data from disk and converting them into numpy array for further processing? I have been really tired since the following code takes number of days to reading (and converting into numpy array) the thousands of files.

```
import glob, gdal, numpy as np
tiff_files = glob.glob('*.tif')    
all_data = []
for f in tiff_files:
    data_open = gdal.Open(f)
    data_array = data_open.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32) 
    all_data.append(data_array)
```

How can I apply multiprocessing for above case?

Comment: Can you provide more context? How big are the images? What are you doing with the data after you read them? Why do you read them all at once instead of one at a time?

Comment: Have a look at Sean Gilles' rasterio: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio  it should be a bit more efficient than the way you're currently reading each geotiff into a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not to hard as your tiff_files are already a list, an important question is Does order matter - do the results have to be in the same order as the original files.  If not

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def handle_tiff(some_file):
    data_open = gdal.Open(some_file)
    data_array = data_open.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32) 
    return data_array

tiff_files = glob.glob('*.tif') 
p = Pool(cpu_count()- an_integer)
all_data = p.map(handle_tiff, tiff_files)
```

In the above code you can just use cpu_count without subtracting an integer.

In response to your question some_file is a path from the list tiff_files.  Note so the p.map maps each item in the list tiff_files to the function handle_tiff and spawns some number of threads.  The list is broken into discrete chunks and each chunk assigned to a different thread. Then the filepath's in each chunk are sequentially submitted to the function.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Yes, the order does not matter. So I am going to test your code.

Comment: Just a note, if you are heavily I/O bound, multiprocessing may not speed things up significantly (and can even slow it down) -- if so, spread your data across multiple spindles and/or faster disks.

Comment: @PyNEwbie by the way, where did you use some_file after defining it. Does it require for loop after the tiff_files?